# Aggregating values per day using a formula

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe below

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
'datetime': ['2021-03-15', '2021-03-15', '2021-03-17', '2021-03-17', '2021-03-12', '2021-03-12', '2021-12-14', '2021-04-07', '2021-07-09', '2021-04-25', '2021-04-25'],
'n': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
't': [1.41, 1.05, 2.01, 0.79, 1.37, 2.19, 1.28, 1.9, 0.97, 1.48, 1.96],
'leq': [73.95284344, 75.08732477, 42.52073186, 14.16069694, 59.36296547, 48.7827182, 44.48691532, 63.63032644, 95.20787662, 61.38061937, 12.50041565]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and would like to generate daily values for each user using the formula below

[image]

My concern is the varying number of n for each day.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mathematical formula for your use case would be

```
10*np.log(1/np.sum(df['t'])*np.sum((df['t']*(np.power(10, df['leq']/10)))))
```

We want the daily average for each id on each day, which means for id `1` you have `2` unique days `2021-03-15` and `2021-03-17`. SO the formula needs to be applied to each group.

```
df['Daily_Average'] = 0
for group_id, group_df in df.groupby(['id','datetime']):
    df.loc[(df['id'] == group_id[0]) & (df['datetime'] == group_id[1]), 'Daily_Average'] = 10*np.log(1/np.sum(group_df['t'])*np.sum((group_df['t']*(np.power(10, group_df['leq']/10)))))
```

Output:

```
df
    id    datetime  n     t        leq  Daily_Average
0    1  2021-03-15  1  1.41  73.952843     171.482002
1    1  2021-03-15  2  1.05  75.087325     171.482002
2    1  2021-03-17  1  2.01  42.520732      94.598488
3    1  2021-03-17  2  0.79  14.160697      94.598488
4    2  2021-03-12  1  1.37  59.362965     128.447851
5    2  2021-03-12  2  2.19  48.782718     128.447851
6    2  2021-12-14  1  1.28  44.486915     102.434908
7    3  2021-04-07  1  1.90  63.630326     146.514241
8    3  2021-07-09  1  0.97  95.207877     219.224237
9    3  2021-04-25  1  1.48  61.380619     132.899977
10   3  2021-04-25  2  1.96  12.500416     132.899977
```

You can set index on `id, Date and Daily average` for better visibility.

```
df.set_index(['id', 'datetime', 'Daily_Average', 'n'])
```

This gives us :

```
                                  t        leq
id datetime   Daily_Average n                 
1  2021-03-15 171.482002    1  1.41  73.952843
                            2  1.05  75.087325
   2021-03-17 94.598488     1  2.01  42.520732
                            2  0.79  14.160697
2  2021-03-12 128.447851    1  1.37  59.362965
                            2  2.19  48.782718
   2021-12-14 102.434908    1  1.28  44.486915
3  2021-04-07 146.514241    1  1.90  63.630326
   2021-07-09 219.224237    1  0.97  95.207877
   2021-04-25 132.899977    1  1.48  61.380619
                            2  1.96  12.500416
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time and offering assistance. The goal was to find daily averages per subject  and not a single value for the entire dataset. Thanks once again!

Comment: I didn't get you, what do you mean by per subject? The formula that you have gives you a sclar quantity, not a vector

Comment: @StephenOkiya could you explain what exactly is your expected output

Comment: Sorry for not for being clear in my post. The goal is to find average for each day and person. For example, id 1 has 2 values (n = 2) for 2021-03-15. So the t and leq values for these two days. Another example, id 2 has 1 value (n = 1) for 2021-12-14 hence this should be used to calculate the daily average. Let me know in case its not clear

Comment: okay so  you want to do it for each of your id's and for each id, you want that legtotal?

Comment: I see there are 4 id 1

Comment: for each id and day. So id 1 should have value for 2021-03-15 and 2021-03-17. It would be good to have a new column in the same data frame with the daily aggregates instead of having a collapsed one

Comment: You said `Another example, id 2 has 1 value (n = 1) for 2021-12-14` but that is not the case, id 2 has 2 value of same date(2021-03-12) and 2 n's therefore

Comment: Thanks so much @Himanshu Poddar for the excellent solution.